# JSON.stringify(data) populate variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data from my model coming back to me.  In the past i have used

```
$.parseJSON(data);
```

This I would then use $.each and loop through the data and output arrays into tables rows/columns.

Instead what I want to do is have a number of variable in which I can decide whether to set to value of a textbox or div or any element

I was seeing this JSON.stringify and wondered about if it is more practical in that it is putting the data into a string, except I wasn't sure HOW to really use it.

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Example:

```
<li><a href="#">USERID</a></li>
```

OR

```
<input type=text id="whatever">
```

I can see in chrome dev tools output of data is

```
Object {ntid: "bthorn", AuthGroup: "admin", DOCCCOGroup: "sst"}
```

What is the easiest way to JUST get that "ntid" value?

```
var ntid = data["ntid"] ???
```

Comment: Sure .. Check out this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/ba0wxes8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.parseJSON` is the same as `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify` the former parses a JSON string into a javascript object, the latter converts a javascript object into a JSON string.

And answering your question you could access using `data.ntid` or `data["ntid"]`

```
var json = '{ "foo": "bar", "test": "stack" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(json); // obj = { foo: "bar", test: "stack" };

var obj = { foo: "bar", test: "stack" };
var json = JSON.stringify(obj); //'{ "foo": "bar", "test": "stack" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(data.ntid)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7sp5jwgf/)

Use the key of the value you want to get